# Regex for searching any of 3 different strings on a string

Tags: regex

I want to search any of the three different strings and their variations on a given string.

If any of these three strings CAT-17*, or CAT-19*, or CAT-20* are there on a given string, then there is a match. Here the asterisk means zero or more characters, were the string may have subsequent characters (example: CAT-17, or CAT-17J1, or CAT-19, or CAT-19F2, or CAT-20, or CAT-20MM3)

I have [tried](https://regex101.com/r/BlH1QJ/1) the below regex and it is matching CAT-20J1 but not CAT-20, same goes for other strings also. if I add some subsequent characters it is matching, but not when the string is alone.

```
\b(?:CAT-17([\w]+)|CAT-19([\w]+)|CAT-20([\w]+))\b
```

How can I fix this for regex to accept 0 or more characters after the main string, for example, CAT-20

Comment: `+` means *1 or more*, `*` means *0 or more*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first suggestion: [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/BlH1QJ/3)

```
/\bCAT-(17|19|20)\w*\b/g
```

Explained:

- `\b` Word boundary
- `CAT-` matches exactly "`CAT-`"
- `(17|19|20)` followed by one of this group options
- `\w` word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `*` zero or more times **(Here's the catch!)**
- `\b` till a word boundary.

Comment: Thanks, Roko, this saved my day!

Comment: @Dan happy to save it ;)